# How to sort a set of buckets by a field in the results

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to sort the buckets by a field "priority", defined as text, but I have no idea how to do it.

Do you mind to help me with this?

I've tried bucket_sort but ES gives an error about the type, same with sort and order.

this is the aggregations query

```
{
 "query": {
   [...]
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "priority.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggregations": {
    "by_family": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "familyId",
        "size": 25,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "same_family": {
          "top_hits": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 1,
            "version": false,
            "explain": false,
            "highlight": {
              "pre_tags": [
                "<search>"
              ],
              "post_tags": [
                "</search>"
              ],
              "fields": {
                "title*": {
                  "type": "unified"
                }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

an example of results is:

```
{
  "responses" : [
    {
      "took" : 13117,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 10,
        "successful" : 10,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : 1754299,
        "max_score" : null,
        "hits" : [...]
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "by_family" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 40,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 1753462,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : 39031576,
              "doc_count" : 92,
              "same_family" : {
                "hits" : {
                  "total" : 92,
                  "max_score" : 10.636923,
                  "hits" : [
                    {
                      "_index" : "idx5-1554993721115",
                      "_type" : "_doc",
                      "_id" : "589403A-333506350",
                      "_score" : 10.636923,
                      "_source" : {
                        "number" : "589403A",
                        "suggest" : {
                          "input" : [
                            "589403A"
                          ]
                        },
                        "id" : "589403A-333506350",
                        "familyRepresentative" : 1,
                        "familyId" : 39031576,
                        "countryCode" : "NZ",
                        "number" : "589403",
                        "kind" : "A",
                        "family" : [ ],
                        "priority" : "20070425", <-------------
                        "created" : "2019-04-14",
                        "modified" : null,
                        "title" : [...],
```

I want to sort buckets aggregations (asc/desc) by field "priority" defined as text in the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define another sub-aggregation (like max or min depending on how you want to sort) and then sort the parent `terms` aggregation by that metric. Remember that in your buckets by `familyId`, the documents might all have different values for the the `priority` field, so it doesn't make sense to sort buckets on a given document field, only on the aggregated value of that given field.

```
{
 "query": {
   [...]
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "priority.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggregations": {
    "by_family": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "familyId",
        "size": 25,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "max_priority": "desc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "max_priority": {
          "max": {
              "script": "Long.parseLong(doc['priority.keyword'].value)"
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but then I have this error ```"failed_shards" : [
          {
             "reason" : {
              "type":"illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [priority] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
            }
          }
        ],``` and if I use keyword then ```"reason":"Expected numeric type on field [priority.keyword], but got [keyword]"```

Comment: Ok it should be on the `priority.keyword` field, fixed

Comment: thank you, Val. But now I got the error ```"reason" : "Expected numeric type on field [priority.keyword], but got [keyword]"```, oh, I forgot the ES version is 6.5

Comment: Ok, ideally, the `priority` field should not be a keyword but a long or integer. I've modified the query to parse the priority string into a long, so that should work, but it is not ideal performance-wise depending on the volume of documents you have.

Answer (score 0):

let's try this one for simplicity:

```
'aggs' => [
    'by_family' => [
        'terms' => [
            'field' => 'familyId',
            'order' => [ '_term' => 'asc' ]
        ],
    ],
]
```

The script above will focus on your `familyId` field, then you may change the value of the `_term` there to `asc` or `desc` to change the order accordingly